what arguments are passed in the accounts method in program.methods."MyProgramInstructions"().accounts({?}).instructions()
I am trying to follow Solana Bootcamp 2024 project 9 that I will use as boilerplate for my dapp.
When I get to test the program I run into an error and I can't find  anything in the docs (or I don't understand it).
Error:
  tests/tokenlottery.spec.ts:47:17 - error TS2345: Argument of type '{ tokenProgram: anchor.web3.PublicKey; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ResolvedAccounts<{ name: "payer"; writable: true; signer: true; } | { name: "collectionMint"; writable: true; pda: { seeds: [{ kind: "const"; value: [99, 111, 108, 108, 101, 99, 116, 105, 111, 110, 95, 109, 105, 110, 116]; }]; }; } | ... 8 more ... | { ...; }>'.
      Property 'tokenLottery' is missing in type '{ tokenProgram: anchor.web3.PublicKey; }' but required in type 'Pick<OmitNever<{ payer: Address | undefined; collectionMint: never; collectionAssociatedAccount: never; metadata: never; tokenMetadataProgram: never; masterEdition: never; tokenLottery: Address; assoiateTokenProgram: never; tokenProgram: Address; systemProgram: never; rent: never; }>, "tokenLottery" | "tokenProgram">'.

    47       .accounts({
                       ~
    48         tokenProgram: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    49       })

I have tried to pass all the accounts that are associate with this instruction, but it doesn't seem to work. I can't find the best place to look for the solution either.
So this is my tokenlottery.specs.ts code:
import * as anchor from '@coral-xyz/anchor';
import { Program } from '@coral-xyz/anchor';
import { Keypair } from '@solana/web3.js';
import { Tokenlottery } from '../target/types/tokenlottery';
import { getAssociatedTokenAddressSync } from '@solana/spl-token';
import { TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID } from '@coral-xyz/anchor/dist/cjs/utils/token';

describe('tokenlottery', () => {
  // Configure the client to use the local cluster.
  const provider = anchor.AnchorProvider.env();
  anchor.setProvider(provider);
  const wallet = provider.wallet as anchor.Wallet;
  anchor.setProvider(provider);

  const program = anchor.workspace.Tokenlottery as Program<Tokenlottery>;

  const connection = provider.connection;

  it('should init config and lottery', async () => {
    const slot = await connection.getSlot();
    console.log('Current slot', slot);

    const initConfigIx = await program.methods
      .intializeConfig(
        new anchor.BN(0),
        new anchor.BN(slot + 10),
        new anchor.BN(10000)
      )
      .instruction();

    const blockhashContext = await connection.getLatestBlockhash();

    const tx = new anchor.web3.Transaction({
      feePayer: provider.wallet.publicKey,
      blockhash: blockhashContext.blockhash,
      lastValidBlockHeight: blockhashContext.lastValidBlockHeight,
    }).add(initConfigIx);

    const signature = await anchor.web3.sendAndConfirmTransaction(
      connection,
      tx,
      [wallet.payer]
    );

    const initLotteryIx = await program.methods
      .initializeLottery()
      .accounts({
        tokenProgram: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,  // ERROR HERE
      })
      .instruction();

    const initLotteryTx = new anchor.web3.Transaction({
      blockhash: blockhashContext.blockhash,
      lastValidBlockHeight: blockhashContext.lastValidBlockHeight,
      feePayer: wallet.payer.publicKey,
    }).add(initLotteryIx);

    const sig = await anchor.web3.sendAndConfirmTransaction(
      connection,
      initLotteryTx,
      [wallet.payer]
    );
    console.log(signature, sig);
  });
});

and this is my lib.rs (what matters):
 pub fn initialize_lottery(context: Context<InitializeLottery>) -> Result<()> {
      let signer_seeds: &[&[&[u8]]]  = &[&[
        b"collection-mint".as_ref(),
        &[context.bumps.collection_mint],
      ]];

      /* Create Mint - Minting a Single Token to our Token Account */
      msg!("Creating Mint Account");

      mint_to(
        CpiContext::new_with_signer(
          context.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
          MintTo {
            mint: context.accounts.collection_mint.to_account_info(),
            to: context.accounts.collection_associated_account.to_account_info(),
            authority: context.accounts.collection_mint.to_account_info(),
          },
           signer_seeds,),
           1
      )?;

      /* Create Metadata Account for that token */
      msg!("Creating Metadata Account");

      create_metadata_accounts_v3(
        CpiContext::new_with_signer(
          context.accounts.token_metadata_program.to_account_info(), 
          CreateMetadataAccountsV3 {
            metadata: context.accounts.metadata.to_account_info(),                //metadata account
            mint: context.accounts.collection_mint.to_account_info(),             //collection_mint account          
            mint_authority: context.accounts.collection_mint.to_account_info(),   //mint authority is itself
            payer: context.accounts.payer.to_account_info(),                      //payer
            update_authority: context.accounts.collection_mint.to_account_info(), //update authority itself
            system_program: context.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),    //system program
            rent: context.accounts.rent.to_account_info(),                        //rent
          }, 
          &signer_seeds
        ), 
        DataV2 {
          name: NAME.to_string(),
          symbol: SYMBOL.to_string(),
          uri: URI.to_string(),
          seller_fee_basis_points: 0,
          creators: Some(vec![Creator {
              address: context.accounts.collection_mint.key(),
              verified: false,
              share: 100,
          }]),
          collection: None,
          uses: None,
      },
      true, // is mutable ?
      true, // is update authority the signer?
      Some(CollectionDetails::V1 { size: 0 }), // collection details (set as collection nft)
      )?;

      /* Create Master Edition */

      msg!("Creating Master Edition Account");

      create_master_edition_v3(
        CpiContext::new_with_signer(
          context.accounts.token_metadata_program.to_account_info(), 
          CreateMasterEditionV3 {
            payer: context.accounts.payer.to_account_info(),                 
            mint: context.accounts.collection_mint.to_account_info(), 
            edition: context.accounts.master_edition.to_account_info(),
            mint_authority: context.accounts.collection_mint.to_account_info(),            
            update_authority: context.accounts.collection_mint.to_account_info(),  
            metadata: context.accounts.metadata.to_account_info(),     
            token_program: context.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),  
            system_program: context.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),         
            rent: context.accounts.rent.to_account_info(),                               
          },
          &signer_seeds
        ), 
        Some(0) // Max supply (we wont be doing more than this account)
      )?;

      /* Last Step : Verify the collection */

      msg!("Verifying Collection");

      sign_metadata(
        CpiContext::new_with_signer(
          context.accounts.token_metadata_program.to_account_info(), 
          SignMetadata {
            creator: context.accounts.collection_mint.to_account_info(), //check create_metadata_accounts_v3
            metadata: context.accounts.metadata.to_account_info(), 
          },
          &signer_seeds))?;

      Ok(())
    }

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct InitializeLottery<'info> {
  #[account(mut)]
  pub payer: Signer<'info>,


  #[account(
    init,
    payer = payer,
    mint::decimals = 0,
    mint::authority = collection_mint,
    mint::freeze_authority = collection_mint,
    seeds = [b"collection_mint".as_ref()],
    bump
  )]
  pub collection_mint: InterfaceAccount<'info, Mint>, //this PDA is a mint account so we can't store the bump in the state account

  #[account(
    init,
    payer = payer,
    token::mint = collection_mint,
    token::authority = collection_associated_account,
    seeds = [b"collection_associated_account".as_ref()],
    bump
  )]
  pub collection_associated_account: InterfaceAccount<'info, TokenAccount>,


  //----- next 2 accounts not best practice -----//
  /* Check Metadata program code to see how to derive it */
  #[account(
    mut,
    seeds =[b"metadata", 
      token_metadata_program.key().as_ref(), 
      collection_mint.key().as_ref()
      ],
    bump,
    seeds::program = token_metadata_program.key(),
  )]
  /// CHECKED: Thi is checked by the metadata program
  pub metadata: UncheckedAccount<'info>,

  #[account(
    mut,
    seeds =[
    b"metadata", 
    token_metadata_program.key().as_ref(), 
    collection_mint.key().as_ref(),
    b"edition"
    ],
    bump,
    seeds::program = token_metadata_program.key(),
  )]
  /// CHECKED: This is checked by the metadata program
 
 #[account(
    mut
  )]
  pub token_lottery: Account<'info, TokenLottery>,


  // Programs we are going to need
  pub token_metadata_program: Program<'info, Metadata>,
  pub assoiate_token_program: Program<'info, AssociatedToken>,
  pub token_program: Interface<'info, TokenInterface>,
  pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
  pub rent: Sysvar<'info, Rent>,
}

If anyone could help me debug this and also explain what are we specifying so I can debug this myself in the future, I would be very thankful.
Not sure if this is helpful too:
[features]
idl-build = ["anchor-lang/idl-build", "anchor-spl/idl-build"]
[dependencies]
anchor-lang = "0.30.1"
anchor-spl = {version= "0.30.1", features= ["metadata"]}

In summary, this was a typo on the instruction function in Lib.rs and missing tokenLottery account in the instructions.
Typo:
The seeds passed has 'collection-mint' and not 'collection_mint'.
Instructions part:
I had to get tokenLottery Pubkey.
const tokenLottery = anchor.web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
    [buffer.from(token_lottery)],
    program.programId,
).[0]

// Then this worked:

Let initLotteryIx = await program.methods
    .initializeLottery()
    .accounts({
        tokenLottery,
        tokenProgram: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
    });

What I dont understand is why I dont need to pass an array of all the accounts and these two alone work.
